# document.getElementById(...) is null in Chrome but working on older browsers like Old IE

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error as in the title when I open the console in Chrome and Firefox. However, everything is working fine on older browser like older IE versions. You can check [this image](http://take.ms/4dMin).

I am attaching the script:

```
function MoveNext()
{
    var qno = document.getElementById("txtQueNo").value;
    var qcode = document.getElementById("txtQueCode").value;
    var quetot = document.getElementById("quetot").value;
    var que_avl = document.getElementById("que_avl").value;
    var stdid = document.getElementById("txtStdID").value;
    var oltid = document.getElementById("txtOLTID").value;
    var ans = document.getElementById("txtAnswer").value;
    var time =  document.getElementById("disp").value;
```

I'm adding the [full script for reference](http://ovo.li/WfUFe4).

The issue is on **the last line of the above code**.

Thank you.

Comment: Post the HTML too so we have a [MCVE] to work with

Comment: And you are sure that there is an element with the ID "disp" in your HTML, and that you do not call `document.getElementById("disp")` before that element is loaded?

Comment: Looking at your full script, are you seriously using `eval` just to parse a string as a number?

Comment: Here is the php file: http://ovo.li/GHfI1U

Comment: @Xufox That is used to get the question from a certain number.

Comment: You don’t have an element with the ID `disp`. To parse numbers, use `Number`, not `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

The only occurrence of `"disp"` in your php is as a name and not an ID (`id="txt"`).

You can use `document.getElementsByName("disp")[0].value` instead. This will of course return an array of all elements with `name="disp"` but as you only have one in the php provided, this should be the correct assignment for the 0 based index.